# How to download a past version of a file from Google Drive when Google Drive doesn't recognize it as a single file

Tags: google-drive

I'm trying to restore or download an old version of an [Axure Rapid Prototyping](http://www.axure.com/) file that I saved over in Google Drive. I looked up [Google's documentation on the topic](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), which says:

> Restore recent versions
>
> You can download and keep old copies of PDF files, images, and other
>   files stored in Google Drive.
>
> Go to drive.google.com. 
>   Click on a file. 
>   At the top right, click More [image: three dots menu]. 
>   Click Manage versions. 
>   Click More [image: three dots menu]. 
>   Click Download to save a copy to your computer.

However, on this file, I am not seeing a "manage versions" option under the three dots menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in Google Drive, one can get to the "manage versions" menu from this file in a list but not from the detail view of the file itself.

[image: Google Drive list view showing "manage versions" in the menu]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from my [answer here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101827/what-is-the-actual-version-limit-file-history-on-google-drive/101862#101862), you have to go to the individual file and select the version to download. This will not work for zipped/compressed files.

I'm attaching the screenshot here for reference
[image]

Comment: The screenshot in my question is from an individual file. It is the .rp file extension saved by the application, Axure. It is not a compressed / zipped file. Google Drive doesn't seem to recognize it as a single file though.

Comment: Try checking the versions of your .rp file

Comment: I am not able to get to the versions of the .rp file. That is what my question is about!

Comment: Can you right click on the .rp file in your Google drive and check if there is a revisions option?

Comment: Ah, I see now. That menu option is only available from a list view but not on the detail page of the file itself.

Comment: Could have accepted my answer :p

Comment: Your answer didn't really answer the question - your comment did. That's why I voted up the comment but didn't accept the answer - for clarity on what the solution is. As I mentioned in a comment, "going to the individual file" did not reveal the menu.