# What is the actual version limit / file history on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I'm considering using Google Drive as my primary backup solution. However, I was not able to figure out exactly When Google Drive deletes old versions of a file.

- After 100 versions
- After 30 days

When looking at my files, files seem to get deleted only once **both conditions** are fulfilled. Is that true? (I only have very few files right now in my Google Drive so it is hard to figure it out myself.)

Comment: Vincent, if you have found what you wanted to know then do mark the answer as correct

Comment: @KaranShah I accepted your answer. Thanks. Right now I am running a script which changes a file on drive frequently. I'll let you know as soon as I know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're correct, for non-native versions of files - Google keeps the revisions for either up to 100 revisions or till 30 days (whichever is shorter). However there is a way to keep a revision of a file forever.

One screenshot I took will help for sure:
[image]

Comment: thanks! So the thing is, I found one file in my drive which has 87 versions and dates back to 31 oct 2016 - how is that?

Comment: Is it a non native file? As in gdocs, gsheet? Also, if someone purchases the premium version of G suite, they can have unlimited versions

Comment: It is not a native file (zip)... And I shouldn't have premium :/

Comment: Maybe the policies were different at that time, this is the current policy however. Try creating a new file and check

Comment: In google docs I don't see the option "Keep forever", but there is a "named versions". Are named versions kept forever in google docs?

Comment: This answer seems outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I have been versioning a zip file on Google Drive and just tried to submit my 201th version of the file and got an error.  When I deleted my penultimate recent version and tried again, it let me upload my new version.  So my experience is 200 versions max, given that I am nowhere near the max disk space mentioned in other posts on this thread.